# Injecting entities constructor during denormilization

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, dependency-injection, api-platform.com

I wish to inject one of my entities constructor when creating it, and the following script allows me to do so.  The object I need to inject for my actual application is more complicated than `Bar` in this example, and I wish to utilize a service to create it, however, I understand that injecting a service into an entity is bad juju.

What is the correct way to do this?

```php
namespace App\Entity\Testing;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Post;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\AbstractNormalizer;

#[ORM\Entity]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(), new GetCollection(),
        new Post(
            denormalizationContext: [
                AbstractNormalizer::DEFAULT_CONSTRUCTOR_ARGUMENTS => [
                    Foo::class => ['type' => 'DefaultType', 'bar' => new Bar('FooMissingBarDefaultName')],
                    Bar::class => ['name' => 'BarMissingNameDefaultName'],
                ],
                'groups' => ['foo:write']
            ],
        )
    ],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['foo:read']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['foo:write']],
)]
class Foo
{
    #[ORM\Id] #[ORM\GeneratedValue] #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    public function __construct(
        #[Groups(['foo:read', 'foo:write'])]
        #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
        private string $type,

        #[Groups(['foo:read', 'foo:write'])]
        #[ORM\OneToOne(cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
        #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
        private Bar $bar,
    )
    {}

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getType(): string
    {
        return $this->type;
    }
    public function getBar(): Bar
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}
```

```php
namespace App\Entity\Testing;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

#[ORM\Entity]
#[ApiResource]
class Bar
{
    #[ORM\Id] #[ORM\GeneratedValue] #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    public function __construct(
        #[Groups(['foo:read', 'foo:write'])]
        #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
        private string $name,
    )
    {}

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: The only way I know to accomplish this is to use a Doctrine event listener to set the dependencies after the object is constructed.  There are several examples out there.  But as you say, Doctrine entities frown upon dependency injection.

Comment: @Cerad  Appreciate the comment.  Would like your <frown> opinion on something.  Should I give up attempting to use an entity's constructor?  It seems like the right OOP way of doing things, but I am going in circles.  Thanks

Comment: When instantiating an entity using fetched database information, Doctrine uses reflection to create the object and to directly set the properties.  There is no straight forward way to tell Doctrine to inject additional dependencies.  So it is awkward.  The event listener approach will work but I think it is best to consider them to be just Data Transfer Objects.  So in general, make yourself a Bar service and then pass an entity as an argument to Bar's methods.